# Interpreting pinout and the transfer function for this sensor from its datasheet

Tags: sensor, datasheet

I have [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/d67c/0900766b81384408.pdf) pressure sensor with the following details from the datasheet:

[image]

The diagram for connections is given as follows as Vsupply, GND and Vout:

[image]

But the chip has 6 legs and described as follows:
[image]
[image]

**1-)** What is V1, V2 and Vex?

**2-)** And how can I obtain the transfer function equation? Is it Vout = Vs* (.009*P-.095) ± Error ?

Comment: Tip: enter the part number into the hyperlink anchor rather than "this". Then we don't have to follow the link to know the part number. (I know you've highligthed it on the datasheet clip but it's not as obvious.)

Comment: This is a good question. The datasheet is deficient in this regard. I'd seek clarification from the manufacturer.

Comment: The datasheet specifically states "Pins 4,5 and 6 are NO CONNECTS for unibody package devices". Consequently you do not need to know what V1, V2 and Vex might be.

Comment: @henros:  That looks very much like **the** answer.  Would you like to post it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the pins are listed by name in the package spec, but not further defined, indicates to me that they're either ports for automated end-of-line testing or for diagnostic purposes.  Less likely, but quite possible, is that they're special purpose functions such as fine adjustments or reference voltages that are used only internally or by a few select customers.  In any case, the only advice given is on page 4, where they're listed as no connects.  I'd take that to the bank, as it's possible that some connected conditions could damage the sensor.

The transfer function you listed agreed with the one on page 5, and matches the graph as well as the specs table.  Since it's directly proportional to Vs, if you want good accuracy you should regulate Vs pretty tightly, or alternatively use Vs as a reference to your ADC if you're digitizing the output.